# How to mock anypoint mq in mule munit

Tags: mocking, mule, anypoint-studio, munit

my project has an Anypoint MQ connector - I want to mock it form munit testing  can someone please advise how to mock it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way -

```
 <mock:when messageProcessor=".*:.*" doc:name="Mock_Anypoint_MQ">
         <mock:with-attributes>
             <mock:with-attribute name="doc:name" whereValue="#['abc']"/>
         </mock:with-attributes>
         <mock:then-return payload="#['Message Published!']"/>
 </mock:when>
```

Post again if you are facing any issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this as below

```
 <mock:when messageProcessor="anypoint-mq:publish" doc:name="Mock Anypoint MQ">
            <mock:with-attributes>
                <mock:with-attribute name="doc:name" whereValue="#['Anypoint MQ']"/>
            </mock:with-attributes>
            <mock:then-return payload="#['Message publised successfully.']"/>
        </mock:when>
```